# Logstash avro codec: undefined method `type_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, logstash, avro

I am using logstash:7.6.2 docker image and below is extract of the pipeline

```
input {
    kafka {
        bootstrap_servers => "kafka-svc:9093"
        topics => ["avro-topic"]
        key_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
        value_deserializer_class => "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer"
        codec => avro {
          "schema_uri" => "/tmp/avro_schema.avsc"
        }
    }
}
```

The plugin crashes with below exception.
I compared the schema with event, they match. Any leads on whats the issue?

```
[2020-10-06T05:26:30,157][INFO ][org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash-es] Member logstash-0-bba62026-7a98-44cd-876c-bcdc77bfa801 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator vlab046703.dom046700.lab:9093 (id: 2147482646 rack: null)
warning: thread "Ruby-0-Thread-13: :1" terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
NoMethodError: undefined method `type_sym' for nil:NilClass
  match_schemas at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/schema_compatibility.rb:36
  match_schemas at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:240
      read_data at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:257
     read_union at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:355
      read_data at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:286
    read_record at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:363
           each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1814
    read_record at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:361
      read_data at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:287
           read at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/avro-1.9.2/lib/avro/io.rb:252
         decode at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-codec-avro-3.2.3-java/lib/logstash/codecs/avro.rb:77
  thread_runner at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-kafka-10.0.1-java/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:258
  thread_runner at /usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-integration-kafka-10.0.1-java/lib/logstash/inputs/kafka.rb:257
[2020-10-06T05:26:30,230][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ] A plugin had an unrecoverable error. Will restart this plugin.
  Pipeline_id:kafka_avro_es
```